# react native:there is way to display a decimal number without the rest after the dot?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Is there a way to display a decimal number without the rest after the dot ?

for example :

```
12.689  --> 12

4.67664 --> 4
```

this is my code:

```
the number is  ${((SUM_VALUE_ORD / SUM_VALUE_NET) - 1) * 100}
```

Comment: `Math.floor` ...?

Comment: Math.trunc() ... ?

Comment: parseInt(12.689);